# Java: I keep getting an error when trying to call the shooterExperiments method. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or exactly how to call a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The problem I'm having is with the last line. I get an error at this section that says "**cannot find symbol**". This is not my entire program, only the first section.

```
public class Chap6Project 
    {
    public double shooterExperiment(int dualsPerExperiment, String[] shooters, double[] accuracies, ProbabilitySupplier p)
    {
             shooters[0] = "aaron";
             shooters[1] = "bob";
             shooters[2] = "charlie";
             String aaron = shooters[0];
             String bob = shooters[1];
             String charlie = shooters[2];
             accuracies[0] = 0.33;
             accuracies[1] = 0.5;
             accuracies[2] = 1.0;
             int duelCount = 0;
             boolean aaronAlive = true;
             boolean bobAlive = true;
             boolean charlieAlive = true;
             Chap6Project project = new Chap6Project();
             ProbabilitySupplier random = new ProbabilitySupplier();
             double rateOfSuccess = project.shooterExperiment(1000, shooters, accuracies, random);
             while (duelCount < 1000)
             {
                   int aaronKills = 0;
                   int aaronWin = 0;
                   double aaronAccuracy = random.getAsDouble();
                   if (aaronAccuracy == 0.33)
                   {
                        if (charlieAlive != true)
                        {
                            aaron.shooterExperiment(1000, bob, accuracies[1], random);
```

Comment: can you put your all code

Comment: Also please ensure you have included the full error message

Answer (score 0):

You declare the aaron variable like so:

```
String aaron = shooters[0];
```

and then try to use it like so:

```
aaron.shooterExperiment(1000, bob, accuracies[1], random);
```

and do this all within this method:

```
public double shooterExperiment(int dualsPerExperiment, String[] shooters, 
       double[] accuracies, ProbabilitySupplier p)
```

The aaron variable is a String and Strings have no `shooterExperiment(...)` method. Perhaps you meant to call this method on a different variable? Given what you've posted it's very hard to say. It looks like you're trying to call the `shooterExperiment` method from within itself, meaning making a recursive call, and doing so with incorrect method parameters and on the wrong object, a String object, none of which makes sense.

You'll want to clarify your problem and what your code is supposed to be doing greatly.

Other issues:

- Your code suffers from the parallel array anti-pattern, a program structure that makes it *very* easy to create bugs. Instead create a class to encapsulate your shooter, including its name, health, accuracy, etc. and use a single collection of Shooter objects.

Comment: do you think you could show me an example of how to create that separate class for the shooter?

Comment: @javabeginner: that's not how it works here, and that's not how you will learn. You should first try to create this class yourself, and if you have problems *then* come back here with your code and your questions. But the first thing you should do is re-read your assignment requirements, and then improve your question because based on the code, you must be making wrong assumptions about what you're supposed to be doing.